# Sending HTML email to HCL Notes is not rendered properly in Notes client or webmail

Tags: html, lotus-notes, mime-types

I am sending an html email to my email in Notes client/Webmail but the stylesheet does not seem to be applied so the email look awfull.  When I open the same email in iOS default mail client (from traveler) it looks fine and also if I send it to gmail it looks fine.

I am using Notes client v12.0.1
What can be the cause of that?

The email is sent programmatically and I add the following to the Body field in the sent email. (Truncated)

[image]

This is what it looks like when sent to Notes client

[image]

This is what it looks like in ios mail client

[image]

This is what it looks like in Notes client

[image]

This is the html added to the body field

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="Generator" content="github.com/hyperlinq/hyperlinq" />
<style type='text/css'>
html,body,div,span,iframe,p,pre,a,abbr,acronym,code,del,em,img,ins,q,strong,var,i,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,nav,output,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;vertical-align:baseline;font:inherit;font-size:100%}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{margin:.2em 0 .05em 0;padding:0;border:0;vertical-align:baseline}i,em{font-style:italic}body{margin:0.5em;font-family:Segoe UI,Verdana,sans-serif;font-size:82%;background:rgb(30,30,30);color:rgb(220,220,220)}pre,code,.fixedfont{font-family:Consolas,monospace;font-size:10pt}a,a:visited{text-decoration:none;font-family:Segoe UI Semibold,sans-serif;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer}a:hover,a:visited:hover{text-decoration:underline}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border:2px solid #3887B5;margin:0.3em 0.1em 0.2em 0.1em}table.limit{border-bottom-color:#f83}table.expandable{border-bottom-style:dashed}td,th{vertical-align:top;border:1px solid #3887B5;margin:0}th{position:-webkit-sticky;position:sticky;top:0;z-index:2}th[scope=row]{position:-webkit-sticky;position:sticky;left:0;z-index:2}th{padding:0.05em 0.3em 0.15em 0.3em;text-align:left;background-color:rgb(80,80,80);border:1px solid rgb(50,50,50);color:rgb(220,220,220);padding:0.3em 0.5em;font-size:.95em;font-family:Segoe UI Semibold,sans-serif;font-weight:bold}th.private{font-family:Segoe UI;font-weight:normal;font-style:italic}td.private{background:rgb(50,50,50)}td.private table{background:rgb(30,30,30)}td,th.member{padding:0.1em 0.3em 0.2em 0.3em;position:initial}tr.repeat>th{font-size:90%;font-family:Segoe UI Semibold,sans-serif;border:none;background-color:rgb(80,80,80);color:#999;padding:0.0em 0.2em 0.15em 0.3em}td.typeheader{font-size:.95em;background-color:#3887B5;color:#eee;border:1px solid #3887B5;padding:0 0.3em 0.25em 0.2em}td.n{text-align:right}a,a:link{color:rgb(140,200,255)}a:visited{color:rgb(220,120,235)}a.typeheader,a:link.typeheader,a:visited.typeheader,a:link.extenser,a:visited.extenser{font-family:Segoe UI Semibold,sans-serif;font-size:.95em;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;color:#eee;margin-bottom:-0.1em;float:left}a.difheader,a:link.difheader,a:visited.difheader{color:#ff8}a.extenser,a:link.extenser,a:visited.extenser{margin:0 0 0 0.3em;padding-left:0.5em;padding-right:0.3em}a:hover.extenser{text-decoration:none}span.extenser{font-size:1.1em;line-height:0.8}span.cyclic{padding:0 0.2em 0 0;margin:0;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:bold;margin:2px;font-size:1.5em;line-height:0;vertical-align:middle}.arrow-up,.arrow-down{display:inline-block;margin:0 0.3em 0.15em 0.1em;width:0;height:0;cursor:pointer}.arrow-up{border-left:0.35em solid transparent;border-right:0.35em solid transparent;border-bottom:0.35em solid rgb(30,30,30)}.arrow-down{border-left:0.35em solid transparent;border-right:0.35em solid transparent;border-top:0.35em solid rgb(30,30,30)}table.group{border:none;margin:0}td.group{border:none;padding:0 0.1em}div.spacer{margin:0.6em 0}div.headingpresenter{border:none;border-left:0.2em dotted #E5B679;margin:.8em 0 1em 0.1em;padding-left:.5em}h1.headingpresenter{border:none;padding:0 0 0.35em 0;margin:0;font-family:Segoe UI Semibold,Arial;font-weight:bold;background-color:rgb(30,30,30);color:#E5B679;font-size:1.1em;line-height:0.8}td.summary{background-color:#204D66;color:rgb(220,220,220);font-size:.95em;padding:0.05em 0.3em 0.2em 0.3em}tr.columntotal>td{background-color:rgb(80,80,80);font-family:Segoe UI Semibold;font-weight:bold;font-size:.95em;color:rgb(220,220,220);;text-align:right}.error > table{border-color:#B56172}.error > table > thead > tr > td.summary{background-color:#F4DEE3;color:black}.error > table > thead > tr > td.typeheader{background-color:#B56172}span.graphbar{background:#3887B5;color:#3887B5;padding-bottom:1px;margin-left:-0.2em;margin-right:0.2em}a.graphcolumn,a:link.graphcolumn,a:visited.graphcolumn{color:rgb(140,200,255);text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial;font-size:1em;line-height:1;letter-spacing:-0.2em;margin-left:0.15em;margin-right:0.2em;cursor:pointer}a.collection,a:link.collection,a:visited.collection{color:#80d080}a.reference,a:link.reference,a:visited.reference{color:rgb(130,190,235)}span.meta,span.null{color:#90ee90}span.warning{color:rgb(210,90,90)}span.false{color:#888}span.true{font-weight:bold}.highlight{background:rgb(255,250,13);color:rgb(30,30,30);;padding:2px}code.xml b{color:rgb(140,200,255);font-weight:normal}code.xml i{color:rgb(220,120,255);font-weight:normal;font-style:normal}code.xml em{color:rgb(210,90,90);font-weight:normal;font-style:normal}span.cc{background:#eee;color:black;margin:0 1.5px;padding:0 1px;font-family:Consolas,monospace;border-radius:3px}ol,ul{margin:0.7em 0.3em;padding-left:2.5em}li{margin:0.3em 0}.difadd{background:#070;border:1px solid #090}.difremove{background:#a23;border:1px solid #d32}.rendering{font-style:italic;color:rgb(220,120,255)}p.scriptLog{color:#caa;background:#433;font-family:Consolas,monospace;font-size:9pt;padding:.1em .3em}::-ms-clear{display:none}input,textarea,button,select{font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:1em;padding:.2em}button{padding:.2em .4em}input,textarea,select{margin:.15em 0}input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{margin:0 0.4em 0 0;height:0.9em;width:0.9em}input[type="radio"]:focus,input[type="checkbox"]:focus{outline:thin dotted red}.checkbox-label{vertical-align:middle;position:relative;bottom:.07em;margin-right:.5em}fieldset{margin:0 .2em .4em .1em;border:1pt solid #aaa;padding:.1em .6em .4em .6em}legend{padding:.2em .1em}input,textarea,select,legend{background:black;color:rgb(220,220,220)}input,textarea,select{border:1pt solid rgb(220,220,220)}input[type="range"]{border:none}
</style>
</head>
<body><div class="spacer"><table id="t2"><thead><tr><td class="typeheader" colspan="2">TimeZoneInfo</td></tr><tr id="sum1"><td colspan="2" class="summary">(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><th class="member" title="System.String">Id</th><td>W. Europe Standard Time</td></tr><tr><th class="member" title="System.Boolean">HasIanaId</th><td><span class="false">False</span></td></tr><tr><th class="member" title="System.String">DisplayName</th><td>(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna</td></tr><tr><th class="member" title="System.String">StandardName</th><td>W. Europe Standard Time</td></tr><tr><th class="member" title="System.String">DaylightName</th><td>W. Europe Daylight Time</td></tr><tr><th class="member" title="System.TimeSpan">BaseUtcOffset</th><td>01:00:00</td></tr><tr><th class="member" title="System.Boolean">SupportsDaylightSavingTime</th><td><span class="true">True</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does it look like in the "normal" view? Also, what does it look like when received by non-Notes recipients?

Comment: I could not expose the example. But will create another sample tomorrow. In the notes client It is basically a none css version of the html

Comment: Post updated with screenshots and html

Comment: I have reported this to HCL support will update here when I know more

Answer (score 0):

In my case the css was somehow filtered out even though it contained no javascript, java or ActiveX by ACF. (Active Content Filtering)

You can bypass the ACF using the following notes.ini vars

**For notes client set notes.ini**

BrowserRenderNoFilter=1

**For webmail set server notes.ini**

iNotes_WA_DisableActCntSecurity=1

HCL does not recommend bypassing the ACF.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?id=kb_article&sysparm_article=KB0100231